# Does anyone know why my lights aren't working at all in 4D cinema?

Tags: lighting

Imported from Vectorworks - I've switched on all lights, adjusted the brightness and nothing seems to be working.

I also have LED screens and they don't seem to be working either[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjJEy.jpg)

Comment: Hi, not a c4d expert, but I'd recommend posting a screenshot of your failed render - saying which version of c4d you're using, and a screen grab of your render settings.